# Understanding when user pressed Up/Down Arrow

Tags: c, windows

This Code prints out what user types after enter button pressed.

```
main()
{

HANDLE         stdinInput = 0;
DWORD          numEvents = 0;
DWORD          numEventsRead = 0;
DWORD          numReceivedRecords = 0;
DWORD          fdwSaveOldMode;
DWORD          fdwMode;


char   dataBuffer[100];
int    bufferLen = 0;


stdinInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

if (stdinInput == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        perror("GetStdHandle");

if (! GetConsoleMode(stdinInput, &fdwSaveOldMode) ) 
        perror("GetConsoleMode");

fdwMode = ENABLE_LINE_INPUT | ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT;
if (! SetConsoleMode(stdinInput, fdwMode) ) 
        perror("SetConsoleMode"); 


for(; ; )
{


   GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(stdinInput, &numEvents);

   if (numEvents != 0) {

       INPUT_RECORD eventBuffer;

      ReadConsoleInputA(stdinInput, &eventBuffer, 1, &numEventsRead);


        if (eventBuffer.EventType == KEY_EVENT) {

            if(eventBuffer.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)
            {
                if(eventBuffer.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar != 0)
                {
                    printf("%c",eventBuffer.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar);
                    dataBuffer[bufferLen++] = eventBuffer.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar;
                    dataBuffer[bufferLen]  = '\0';            

                    if ( dataBuffer[bufferLen] == 99 || eventBuffer.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar == '\r' ) {
                    printf("User Wrote: %s\n",dataBuffer);

                    memset(dataBuffer,0,sizeof(dataBuffer));
                    bufferLen = 0;
                    }
                }


            }
        }

    }
}

}
```

Now i want make it detect when user presses Up/Down Arrow and print out "Up/Down Arrow pressed" without need to press Enter.

Thought to use Virtual Key Codes with GetKeyState() but cant complete it.

Any idea on how to achieve something like this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the virtual key code.  Like this:

```
    if (eventBuffer.EventType == KEY_EVENT) {
        if(eventBuffer.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown) {
            switch (eventBuffer.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode) {
                case VK_DOWN: printf("Down arrow pressed\n"); break;
                case VK_UP:   printf("Up arrow pressed\n"); break;
                default: {
                    // Rest of your code...
                }
```